# Enable HDR Option for UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is it even possible to enable the HDR option from within my application? I assumed it would be there automatically. I looked for additional mediaTypes, thinking maybe kUTTypeHDRImage might be an option, but no such luck. It's not an additional source type, nor is it available through cameraCaptureMode.

```
ipc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
ipc.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage];
```

No mention of it in the documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The HDR option is specific to the Camera app and is not available through the API.

You should file an enhancement request at http://bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: Thank you. That is the confirmation I was looking for, and I appreciate the link. I'll use it.

Comment: And now??
I know about `isVideoHDRSupported` and it is not supported when preset is set to `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto`

Answer (score 0):

It's not a separate media type; it's still an image, and (to my knowledge) still a JPEG. I think what Camera is doing is taking multiple images at different exposure levels and combining them together; that's why it takes so long.

Comment: OK, so how do I enable the HDR option when I use the UIImagePickerController from within my application?

Comment: There's a reasonably good chance that Camera.app isn't using UIImagePickerController, and that HDR hasn't been added to UIImagePickerController yet (try profiling it with CPU Sampler/Shark in Instruments). There might be some private APIs...