# How to use HDR with custom AVFoundation based Camera app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, hdr

I use the `AVFoundation`framework to create a custom camera app.

**Is it possible to capture a photo with HDR for a custom camera app, i.e., is HDR somewhere exposed in the camera api?**

Answer (score 4):

Had the same question and found an answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814692/enable-hdr-option-for-uiimagepickercontroller) SA question.

HDR is unique to the Camera.app from Apple and is not available to developers through an API.

Comment: What does `isVideoHDRSupported` do exactly?