# HDR mode with AVFoundation

Tags: ios, avfoundation, swift4

I am working on a custom camera implementation and have to implement HDR images.

Now i was under the impression the `isVideoHDREnabled` key helps us to implement this along with the `automaticallyAdjustsVideoHDREnabled` key.

But [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29085088/how-to-use-hdr-with-custom-avfoundation-based-camera-app) answer seems to state otherwise.

So basically my question is regarding how HDR can be implemented:

1. Is it possible using the above mentioned keys as opposed to the linked answer?
2. [Capturing a Bracketed Photo Sequence](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/PhotoCaptureGuide/index.html) is mentioned in the linked url which seems to be quite close to the HDR effect. Is this the closest way of implementation?

Answer (score 0):

The methods you described, `isVideoHDREnabled` and `automaticallyAdjustsVideoHDREnabled` are for camera preview.  They do not reflect photo capture.

Far as I know there is not easy way to do HDR with AVFoundation.  You would have to do bracketing and fused the images with your own methods.